# Error al enviar mail con phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

estoy tratando de enviar un mail con la librería phpmailer, en local me funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo he subido a un hosting me devuelve el siguiente error:
Could not instantiate mail function.

La configuración que tengo es la siguiente:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

require_once('lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//indico a la clase que use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

//permite modo debug para ver mensajes de las cosas que van ocurriendo
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Debo de hacer autenticación SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

//indico el puerto que usa Gmail
$mail->Port = 465;

//indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'Restaurante ');
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $nombre);
$mail->Subject = "Nuevo mensaje recibido .";
$mail->msgHTML($mensaje);

//indico destinatario
//$address = "xxx@gmail.com";
$address = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->addAddress($address, "Restaurante");

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Error al enviar: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado!";
}
```

Sabeis que puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Pero ¿el error te lo da aquí: `echo "Error al enviar: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;` o te dice sólo `Could not instantiate mail function`? También asegúrate de que estás indicando la ruta correctamente `lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php` En ese caso `lib` es un subdirectorio del directorio en el que estás ejecutando el PHP de envío de emails.

Comment: En el `script` te esta faltando incluir el archivo `require_once('lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');`, y deberías recibir un error por eso.

Comment: El error en el log es este: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/llgmjzcq/public_html/lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1520

Comment: He añadido la linea (require_once('lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');) y tampoco funciona, sigue dando el mimso fallo. Tambien he comentado la linea $mail->isSMTP(); y nada, no envia email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya esta solucionado. El problema era que tenia que generar una contraseña de aplicación. Al parecer ahora gmail quiere utilizar una contraseña propia para utilizar la cuenta desde un app.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He modificado algunas cosas y ahora me lanza este error:

```
2017-04-09 08:33:17 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```